# Storelocator magento hide stores at start

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, magento

I have this [Store Locator](http://www.magestore.com/magento-store-locator-extension.html)

Installed on my website. It's all working fine and well, but it's a bit slow. This is because there are 500 stores located on the map.

[image: stores]

Edit:

I am looking for this!:

https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/simple_example.html?compiled

Can somebody explain me how to implement this (javascript), into a magento site?

Comment: add the js too. it is related to js

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to build your own module for this.

try this module creator: http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

on the (Need Add Single Table Model) put yes, and then select (Need Backend Model Manager) and fill the fields.

Basically in your case you need the following fields (store name, store lat, store long, store full address, etc..)

the module will provide you with manager in the backend to manage and create stores easily.

then you have to style the list on the front end..

print them in the same format used in the example (you should use this format: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/data.json)

and finally load the js and it should work perfectly.

Let me know if it worked or you are still facing any issue?